# Is it possible to combine two/multiple MST DisplayPort hubs?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport

I have two DP++ ports (let's call them DP01 and DP02) in business PC.
I want to add 3rd monitor.
Is MST (multi-stream) hub 1-to-2 (with ports - call them DP11 and DP12) plugged to DP01 enough?

- MST hub plugged to DP01
- Monitor 1 plugged to hub's DP11
- Monitor 2 plugged to hubs' DP12
- Monitor 3 plugged to PC's DP02

Or I need a 1-to-4 hub plugged to DP01?

May I have 2 MST hubs plugged to DP01 and DP02?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Three monitors connected to PC with use of DisplayPort multistream hub]

This works for me. Three monitors (three independent desktops). Splitter powered from USB port.